# How to pre format a string to show hyperlink in frontend using django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model in which I accept string data in the char field. this is populated through Django admin field.

Models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
   overview = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=False)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Test
def testView(request):
    data = Test.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'abc.html', {'data': data})
```

my template which has html

```
<p style="text-align: center; color: black">{{data.overview  | linebreaks}}</p>
```

this mock response of data:

```
"with the great power comes the great responsibility.
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/">connect</a>" from backend.
```

how to show this as a link inside the paragraph in the front end.

the link might be present anywhere positioned in the paragraph as entered by the text in django-admin

currently the whole anchor tag is displayed instead of link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your question is not clear enough.**

However. For links, you can use `URLField` instead of `CharField`.

[To converts URLs and email addresses in text.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize)

If you are not sure where the link might be in the text, you should use RegEx:

```
url_re = re.compile(r'^www.[a-zA-z$#./?=:;+&@{}|,%<>~0-9]*', re.IGNORECASE)
words = word_split_re.split(str(text))

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if '.' in word or '@' in word or ':' in word:
        lead, middle, trail = '', word, ''
        lead, middle, trail = trim_punctuation(lead, middle, trail

    if url_re.match(middle):
                url = smart_urlquote('http://%s' % html.unescape(middle))
                klass = "js-css-class"
```

Comment: No, i don't want to use a URL field in models. sometimes the link might or might not be present in paragraph at particular position . so i am trying to preformat itself while ingesting data into char field